# Почему при попытке зашифровать системный раздел на VeraCrypt неактивен флажок "Ключевые файлы"?

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, veracrypt

Почему при попытке зашифровать системный раздел на VeraCrypt неактивен флажок "Ключевые файлы"?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ключевой файл для системного диска невозможно использовать по техническим причинам. Ведь он или

а) тоже зашифрован, если на том же разделе,

или

б) отсутствует до загрузки системы, если на другом разделе.

Это примерно как запаролить архив и сохранить пароль к нему в нем самом. Без пароля не распакуешь, но чтобы получить пароль, нужно распаковать.

Comment: Однако здесь этот флажок активен, хотя тоже шифруется системный раздел:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUUBnKeAm6I&t=78s

Comment: А здесь тоже не активен https://youtu.be/mMyfmy__LZc

Comment: Не знаете, возможно ли в таком случае зашифровать системный раздел с использованием USB-токена? Просто этот визард ни разу не предлагает использовать токен. Я думал, это именно через "ключевые файлы" делается